# Getting the first row of the mysql resource string?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Here is my problem.
I need more than one row from the database, and i need the first row for certain task and then go through all the list again to create a record set.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$firstrow = //extract first row from database
//add display some field from it


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   //display all of them
}
```

Now, how to extract just the first row?

Comment: What is the first row in a table ?

Comment: @M42: He wants the first row in the recordset, clearly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using mysql_fetch_assoc() not only fetches a row, it also moves the internal pointer of the result set to the next row. To reset the result resource to the first row, you need to use mysql_data_seek().

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$firstrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

// reset the result resource
mysql_data_seek($result, 0);


while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   //display all of them
}
```

Comment: How inefficient. Why on earth would you want to do a seek operation and retrieve the first row again, when you've already extracted it?

Comment: You need to ask @mrNepal why he wants to do it. There may be a very good reason. On the other hand, if there is no particular reason, I agree that it's not the optimal approach. I simply answered the question as it was put.

Comment: I can't understand why the downvote. This is the perfect answer to my problem. I reason I need the first row and then re-run with the results, is because I am using same result set for 1) Display the full  content and 2) To show other related content.

Comment: @mrNepal: It's good that you got what you wanted, but it might be worth looking at some of the other answers that you've got and wondering if there might be something that you're missing.

Comment: Yes... I have seen all the answers, the next answer is almost the same and your answer didn't work for me. It was the first answer that i tried to implement but... it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)`, you get a row. So, instead of doing it repeatedly in a loop, just do it once:

```
$result = mysql_query("...");
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $firstRow = $row;

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       // all the rest
   }
}
```

Disclaimer: this could be prettier code, but you get the idea!

Comment: @Andrew: Eh? What internal pointer. I don't see why this snippet should not work.

Comment: Oh, you wanted to do the first row again for some reason; I missed that in your original question. It's hugely more efficient to just continue through the list. You already have the first row; why retrieve it a second time???

Comment: @mrNepal: It's not "wrong/incorrect"; it's the best approach to the wider problem that you are attempting to solve. The fact that you asked the question in the first place makes you unqualified to decide otherwise. Your downvote is rude. I'm so glad that I took the time to help you. Good luck in the future.

Comment: BTW, didn't you read my comment, even after using the `while` I only got only one row...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the rows from the first one again then try the following

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result){
    $firstRow = $row;
    mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       //display all of them
    }
}
```

More about mysql_data_seek here: [PHP: mysql_data_seek - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php)

Comment: Same comment as earlier answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **Object oriented style** :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $firstRow = $row;
    mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

    while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       //display all of them
    }
}
```