# Why my SELECT * statement doesn't select first row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have DB table `products` with 3 rows but only last two are being outputted.  i don't know if i'm doing something wrong, but here is the code:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM products";
    $query = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    $fetched_array = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo $row\['name'\];
    }
```

even `var_dump()` showw only two last products and not all 3 including first row.

"iPhone 7" is not being [outputted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ECl5.png).

Comment: `echo $row['name'];` What it returns to you?

Comment: @SaadSuri 2nd and 3rd rows `Macbook Pro 2015Dell XPS`

Comment: the reason is that you have two `fetching` statements - `mysqli_fetch_array` called the first time consumes the first entry in recordset

Comment: i think this link will help u
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614613/getting-the-first-row-of-the-mysql-resource-string

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614613/getting-the-first-row-of-the-mysql-resource-string

Comment: @AhsanHabib Thank you, looks like `mysql_data_seek().` is what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try simply removing the initial `mysqli_fetch_array` like this:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM products";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem. It's really weird that the language acts like that. It's not like first statement removes it from DB, so second statement should still output it. What if I really had to have many fetch statement? Sometimes I don't understand computers.

Comment: It's not __weird__, it's rather clear - `mysqli_fetch_array` fetches row by row in a result set. So if you call `mysqli_fetch_array` once - __first__ row is fetched. And consequent calls to `mysqli_fetch_array` will fetch __next__ rows.

Comment: It's to do with the `cursor` and how it is moved after certain tasks.. There are ways around this behaviour though - either store recordset in an array `mysqli_fetchall()` or explicitly rewind the recordset to it's initial ( or other ) position using `mysqli_data_seek()` ~ OO versions of these functions are available

Comment: @RamRaider But when I change my code to this `$items = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $items = $row['name'];
}` I get only last row using `var_dump($items);`

Comment: `$items = $row['name'];` should be `$items[] = $row['name'];`

Answer (score 1):

you use fetch action 2 times .use it :

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM products";
$query = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: I did change my code and I stll get only one row `$items = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $items = $row['name'];
}`

Comment: it's depend on your table after group by . please show your table content

Comment: There is link in OP if thats what you mean

Comment: If I echo `$row['name']` I get all rows, if I save to $items and var_Dump it only last item is outputted

Comment: It's normal.because after finishing loop $row contain last row

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM products";
if ($sm_result = mysqli_query($dbc, $q)) {
    foreach ($sm_result as $row) {
        echo $row['name'];
    }
}
```